# What is a good way to have both subscriptions & one-time charges in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

In my current setup I'm using subscription-based invoices and I would like to add one-time charges for the businesses that are marked as debtors when the maximum number of payment retries is reached. Debtors would need to make the one-time payment in order to recover access to their account.

So, my idea was to have `invoice.paid` for handling subscriptions paid and `charge.succeeded` for handling one-time charges. The way that I handle the charges for one-time payments only is by making use of guest customers and leaving the customer field null. That way, if customer field is `null` in the charge object, I know for sure that it comes from a one-time payment and not from a subscription charge.

My solution is something similar to this (adapted to this question):

```js
exports.webhook = async function (event, signature) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'invoice.paid':
      //Do subscription backend processing
      break
    case 'charge.suceeded':
      if (!event.data.object.customer) {
        // Do one-time payment backend processing
      }
      break
  }
}
```

Is this a valid solution to my use case? Is there any better way to handle this situation?

Comment: What you have tried? Please add your code snippet for better resolution. (don't post sensitive data over here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the one-off charges to be paid at the same time with the Subscription Invoices?

If yes, I recommend you to listen to the `invoice.created` event [0] and create the one-off InvoiceItem with the Invoice ID [1] from the event. It will add the item to the upcoming Invoice, before it’s finalized. Later, when you receive the `invoice.paid` webhook event, you can check if the event Invoice contains the one-off item to decide how to do your processing.

If not, and the one-off payments are made at arbitrary time, you can use the `metadata` field [2] in your PaymentIntent to describe the payment. Then, when you receive the `payment_intent.succeeded` event [3], you can check if the event payload contains the metadata you provided. You can do the same with Invoices, if you want your one-off payments to be more formal. [4]

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.created

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/create#create_invoiceitem-invoice

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-metadata

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.succeeded

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create#create_invoice-metadata

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I went that route and did it with a metadata pair. As I needed that one-off payment to be fully independent from the subscription I just differentiate between the two via metadata values :)